# Why are certain transaction not visible on blockchain.info?

Tags: blockchain

For example this transaction is visible here but not on blockchain.info

https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/4c26a54af671b4b86cebe648134fd3e4f05634cf3b86523c17882d416b28ebb0

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Every node builds it's own blocks. Blockchain.info is simply unaware of the existence of this transaction, it will be aware when it will be implemented in a block that will be broadcasted to the network. In other terms, it will show up on Blockchain.info when it is confirmed.